# How to setup ATI/Intel dual graphics-card driver in Debian

Tags: debian, ati, graphic-card, hybrid-graphics

I have searched it from the Internet, but there is only a solution for Ubuntu.

> Visit: ***http://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/how-to-setup-amdintel-hybrid-graphics-cards-in-linux-ubuntu/***

I think that might not suit Debian, so can anyone tell me how to set it up?

> Distributor ID:   Debian
>   Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.4 (wheezy)
>   Release:    7.4
>   Codename:   wheezy

Comment: which debian ? do you already try something ? debian and ubuntu are different but shares a lot there is chance something working on ubuntu could work on debian but in this case it will not because of the ppa thing he use. but you can try this http://blog.anantshri.info/howto-add-ppa-in-debian/ but I wouldn't recommand it.

Comment: @Kiwy Thank you.. And do you have other ideas?

Comment: So far no not really what is your debian verison ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have sent it. @Kiwy